# get windows users with group name using C#

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory

I would like to get a list of all users in remote windows os with the groups they belong to.

I am using following code which gets usernames:

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + CurrentOS.Attribute("ip").Value);
directoryEntry.Username = CurrentOS.Attribute("username").Value;
directoryEntry.Password = CurrentOS.Attribute("password").Value;

foreach (DirectoryEntry child in directoryEntry.Children)
{
    if (child.SchemaClassName.Equals("User", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        FoundUsers.Add(new UserDetail(child.Name,""));
    }
}
```

Can someone guide me how to get groups the user belong to(ex. test, administrator) using previous code.